# Integrate a Windows service with aspnetboilerplate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, console-application, aspnetboilerplate

**Goal**

Ok, so my aim here is to have a windows service run alongside my aspnetboilerplate web application. The reason for the windows service is that it will run the Hangfire background jobs, from a completely separate virtual server.

**Configuration**

This is the template i used to get things going 
[image]

**FYI, everything is working from from the web application.**

Here is the Service program file (i am using Topshelf but i don't think that matters).

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>
{
    x.Service<PortalService>(sc =>
    {
        sc.ConstructUsing(() => new PortalService());

        sc.WhenStarted((tc, hostControl) => tc.Start(hostControl));
        sc.WhenStopped((tc, hostControl) => tc.Stop(hostControl));
    });

    x.UseLog4Net();
    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
    x.SetServiceName(PortalService.ServiceName);
    x.SetDisplayName(PortalService.ServiceDisplayName);
    x.SetDescription(PortalService.ServiceDescription);
    x.StartAutomatically();
});
```

Here is the Service Module

```
[DependsOn(typeof(PortalCoreModule), typeof(PortalEntityFrameworkModule), typeof(PortalApplicationModule), typeof(AbpHangfireModule))]
public class PortalServiceModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(PortalServiceModule).GetAssembly());
    }

    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.BackgroundJobs.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.GlobalConfiguration.UseSqlServerStorage(PortalConsts.ConnectionStringName, new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true
            });

            config.Server = new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] {BackgroundJobQueueNames.Critical, BackgroundJobQueueNames.Autotask, BackgroundJobQueueNames.Default}
            });

            config.GlobalConfiguration.UseConsole();
        });

        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new DisableMultipleQueuedItemsFilter());
    }
}
```

And then here is my Service code

```
public class PortalService : ServiceControl
{
    public const string ServiceName = "PortalWorker";
    public const string ServiceDisplayName = "Portal Worker";
    public const string ServiceDescription = "Process the background jobs for the Portal.";

    private AbpBootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        _bootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<PortalServiceModule>();

        _bootstrapper.IocManager
            .IocContainer
            .AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config"));

        _bootstrapper.Initialize();
        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        _bootstrapper.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Yet every time i run the service, i get the following exception

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: 'No component for supporting the service Portal.BackupMonitoring.IBackupMonitoringManager was found'

However, if i was to run the Web application, it works fine, so to me its not an issue with IBackupMonitoringManager. It must be something to do with the Service not being able to register against the DI.

I have had a look in this repo for examples https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples

But the examples are either massively out of date, or i cannot see an example of a console application with a dot net core web application.

Any help on where to get started with this would be greatly appreciated.

## Update

Here is the new exception when a job tries to execute.

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: 'Can't create component
>   'Portal.Authorization.Users.UserManager' as it has dependencies to be
>   satisfied.
>
> 'Portal.Authorization.Users.UserManager' is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>   - Service 'Portal.Authorization.Roles.RoleManager' which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.
>   'Portal.Authorization.Roles.RoleManager' is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>   - Service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleValidator`1[[Portal.Authorization.Roles.Role,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[[Abp.Authorization.Roles.AbpRoleManager`2[[Portal.Authorization.Roles.Role,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[Portal.Authorization.Users.User, Portal.Core,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Abp.ZeroCore,
>   Version=3.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not
>   registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher`1[[Portal.Authorization.Users.User,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
>   which was not registered.
>   - Service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserValidator`1[[Portal.Authorization.Users.User,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordValidator`1[[Portal.Authorization.Users.User,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'System.IServiceProvider' which was not registered.
>   - Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[Portal.Authorization.Users.User,
>   Portal.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]' which was not registered. '

Comment: Where is `IBackupMonitoringManager` injected?

Comment: @aaron ok so i managed to resolve that to a certain degree. The Service project was using an old connection string and thus a different database. Correcting this got rid of this particular error. However i am now getting this error `Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component 'Portal.Authorization.Users.UserManager' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.`    The problem i've got is that the `BackupMonitoringManager` implementation does not reference `Portal.Authorization.Users.UserManager`

Comment: Infact let me correct that i've just had a further look into it and the `BackupMonitoringManager` references `GroupManager` which itself depends on `UserManager`.

Comment: It's injected all over the application. However in this instance i believe it is trying to resolve it when it's executing the background job like so `manager.AddOrUpdate("Get.Backup.Results", Job.FromExpression<IBackupMonitoringManager>(j => j.GetEmails(null)), "*/15 * * * *", TimeZoneInfo.Local, queue: BackgroundJobQueueNames.Critical);`

Comment: The Service starts up ok and Hangfire starts polling for changes. When that job is executed it throws the exception in the update i've posted. If the code is executed from the web application, it works fine.

Comment: I've added the DependOns to the ServiceModule but it is still giving the same exception. I noticed that this code is called from the startup of the webapplication `IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);`, i'm thinking maybe i need to call this from the Console application as well?

Comment: @aaron do you know how to get a reference to `IServiceCollection services` from the console app?

Comment: Just `new` it. See https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have got this now, so i'm going to post it as the answer, but let me know if there is anything wrong with it.

First of all i had to install Abp.AspNetCore package. This allowed access to the `IServiceCollection.AddAbp()` extension method.

So my `Program.cs` changed to this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Clock.Provider = ClockProviders.Utc;

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);

    services.AddAbp<PortalServiceModule>(options =>
    {
        //Configure Log4Net logging
        options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
            f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
        );
    });

    HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.Service<PortalService>(sc =>
        {
            sc.ConstructUsing(() => new PortalService());

            sc.WhenStarted((tc, hostControl) => tc.Start(hostControl));
            sc.WhenStopped((tc, hostControl) => tc.Stop(hostControl));
        });

        x.UseLog4Net();
        x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        x.SetServiceName(PortalService.ServiceName);
        x.SetDisplayName(PortalService.ServiceDisplayName);
        x.SetDescription(PortalService.ServiceDescription);
        x.StartAutomatically();
    });
}
```

I had some problems with the PortalServiceModule. The automapper configuration is already in the PortalApplicationModule so i may have to revisit this to remove the duplicate code. For the moment, this is what i got working.

```
[DependsOn(typeof(PortalCoreModule), typeof(PortalEntityFrameworkModule), typeof(PortalApplicationModule), typeof(AbpHangfireModule), typeof(AbpZeroCoreModule), typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
public class PortalServiceModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(PortalServiceModule).GetAssembly());

        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<object, int?>().ConvertUsing<NullableIntTypeConverter>();

            // Scan the assembly for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile
            cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(PortalApplicationModule).GetAssembly());
        });

        Configuration.BackgroundJobs.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.GlobalConfiguration.UseSqlServerStorage(PortalConsts.ConnectionStringName, new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true
            });

            config.Server = new BackgroundJobServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                Queues = new[] { BackgroundJobQueueNames.Critical, BackgroundJobQueueNames.Autotask, BackgroundJobQueueNames.Default }
            });

            config.GlobalConfiguration.UseConsole();
        });

        GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new DisableMultipleQueuedItemsFilter());
    }

    public override void PostInitialize()
    {
        HangfireJobsConfigurer.Configure();
    }
}
```

Then my actual service code became this

```
public class PortalService : ServiceControl
{
    public const string ServiceName = "PortalWorker";
    public const string ServiceDisplayName = "Portal Worker";
    public const string ServiceDescription = "Process the background jobs for the Portal.";

    private AbpBootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        _bootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<PortalServiceModule>();

        _bootstrapper.Initialize();

        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        _bootstrapper.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now i can run the background jobs from the windows service, although i will try and reduce the dependencies and duplicate code.